# Appending data from excel in existing SQL Server table using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have some CSV files with data which is recurring and therefore I need to update SQL Server by using this python script.

I have tried updating the Microsoft driver for SQL and that doesn't help me.

Here is my python code :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import time 
from datetime import date
import pandas.io.sql
import pyodbc
import xlrd

server ='asd'
db = 'asd'

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';UID=asd ;PWD=asd')
cursor=conn.cursor()


query = """
INSERT INTO Db.table (
    Emp_ID  ,
    Global_ID,
    Emp_NAME,
    Org,
    SBU,
    BU,
    Sub_BU,
    HR_Location,
    Swipe_Loc,
    Descp,
    InOutDate,
    InTime,
    OutTime,
    ActHrs,
    ShiftCode,
    AttendanceClassification,
    ActualHrs
) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""


InOutDate= date.today()
InTime = time(11,11,11)
OutTime = time(11,11,11)
ActHrs = time(11,11,11)
ActualHrs = time(11,11,11)

values = ('2134123', '123213', 'Eqqwe', 'Org' , 'SBU' , 'BU ', 'Sub_BU' , 'HR_Location' ,'Swipe_Loc' ,' Descp' , InOutDate , InTime , OutTime , ActHrs , 'ShiftCode' ,'AttendanceClassification' ,ActualHrs )   
cursor.execute(query, values)
conn.close()
```

Getting the following error when executing query:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "update.py", line 97, in <module>
cursor.execute(query, values)
pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Optional feature not implemented (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

Comment: What is your primary agenda. Do you just want data in excel sheet to be appended in existing SQL table ? Or you want to do that specifically with python ?

Comment: I Just resolved the issue, It has nothing to do with the connection. The error is cuz of the discrepancy between the date and time formats of python and sql. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the DateTime formats are compatible between python and SQL

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `cursor.commit()` after execute. Execute command can be used only for some selects and read only queries. If you want to change something you shoud add `cursor.commit()` after.